# How to view GET request headers generated by open-uri

Tags: ruby, http, open-uri

I'm using open-uri and I know I can get the response headers with the meta method as below, but I'm wondering how I can view the GET headers generated. Or would I have to use a different library for this?

`page = open('http://www.google.com');`
`page.meta`

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can set the request parameters with `open('http://example.com', 'User-Agent' => 'Me')`, but to see all the headers that will be sent you will probably have to sniff the traffic with a proxy, `ngrep`, or `tcpflow`. Or read the source.

Comment: Thank you. Will take a look at those options.

Comment: Some signing schemes require the request headers to be included in the string-to-sign.   So the headers are needed before forming the request URI.  Sniffing is a bit too late in the process.. I wonder how this can be done.

Answer (score 0):

`open-uri` is a convenience library for quickly fetching and reading files over a network. If that's not your use case, you can use a lower-level library like Net::HTTP to get more control over the connection.